# Angular2 - Array.prototype.filter() in templates

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, data-binding, angular2-template

I have an object `networkInterface` that contains an array of `services`
now I want to make a checkbox input that reflects the existence of a specific `service_id` in the `services` array of the `networkInterface`

JSON example of `interfaces:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":11,
      "name":"External Interface",
      "services":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"Web Service"
         },
         {  
            "id":2,
            "name":"FTP Service"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

now typically (in TypeScript) this would be done with:

```
networkInterfaces.services.filter(i => i.id == service.id)[0]
```

this would return `null` or an object, but how can I do that in my html template? when I try to put it like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="networkInterfaces.services.filter(i => i.id == service.id)[0]">
```

I'm getting this error:

> Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 38 in
>   [networkInterfaces.services.filter(i => i.id == service.id)[0]]

any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to do this in the first place. Every time change detection runs, this filter call will be re-executed. This will drag performance of your page down and might even become unusable. The preferred way is to assign a value to a property and bind to this property instead.

```
constructor() {
  this.prop = interfaces.services.filter(i => i.id == service.id)[0];
}

propChanged(e) {
  interfaces.services.filter(i => i.id == service.id)[0] = e;
}
```

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="prop" (ngModelChange)="propChanged($event)">
```

Comment: yes in fact it was a really bad idea, I eventually did it in a completely different way thanks a lot.